# Trying to access array offset on value of type null al actualizar un archivo en servidor me da este error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hola chicos me da este tipo de error a la hora de actualizar la foto en la base de datos pego la depuración ya que no he dado con la tecla, dándole vueltas.

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el input tipo file con el name="foto_dispositivo" actualice dicho campo, pero este solo actualiza el nombre dela foto en este caso $nombre_foto pero no atino a como declararlo para que pueda subir el archivo al servidor y no lo marque como NULL y actualice en base de datos.
Un saludo, se agradece cualquier ayuda !

***Formulario***

```
<!-- editar -->
<div class="modal fade my-5" id="editar<?php echo $row['id_dispositivo']; ?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="AgregarNuevoDispositivo" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="titulo-modal">Guardar Dispositivo</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <form method="POST" action="EditarDispositivo.php?id_dispositivo=<?php echo $row['id_dispositivo']; ?>" >
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-4">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                                    <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-4">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                                    <i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" name="marca" value="<?php echo $row['marca']; ?>" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-4">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                                    <i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" name="version" value="<?php echo $row['version']; ?>" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-4">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                                    <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input type="file" name="foto_dispositivo" value="<?php echo $row['foto_dispositivo']; ?>" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-4">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                                    <i class="fa fa-text-height" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                                <textarea type="text" name="descripcion" class="form-control"><?php echo $row['descripcion']; ?></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="botones">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cerrar</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="actualizar_dispositivo" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id_dispositivo" value="<?php echo $row['id_dispositivo']; ?>">
                        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Guardar
                    </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Código***

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once ('../../conexion_de_bbdd/config_bd.php');
    if(isset($_POST['actualizar_dispositivo'])){
        try{
            $id_dispositivo = $_POST['id_dispositivo'];
            $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
            $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
            $marca = $_POST['marca'];
            $version = $_POST['version'];
            

            $nombre_foto = $_FILES['foto_dispositivo']['name'];
            $tipo_imagen = $_FILES['foto_dispositivo']['type'];
            $tam_imagen = $_FILES['foto_dispositivo']['size'];
            
            $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/aplicacion/subida_de_archivos/'; //ruta del archivo en el servidor, nunca se inserta en la base de datos.
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto_dispositivo']['tmp_name'],$path.$nombre_foto); //insertar el nombre de la imagen en la base de datos y no la ruta.

            $query_actualizar = $bd->prepare ("UPDATE dispositivo SET nombre = ?,descripcion = ?,version =?,marca = ?, foto_dispositivo = ? WHERE id_dispositivo = ?;");
            //UPDATE dispositivo SET nombre = ?,descripcion = ?,version =?,marca = ?, foto_dispositivo = '$foto' WHERE id_dispositivo = ?; 

            $resultado = $query_actualizar->execute([$nombre,$descripcion,$version,$marca,$nombre_foto,$id_dispositivo]);
            var_dump($path);
            $query_actualizar->debugDumpParams();
            var_dump($resultado);

            if($query_actualizar){
                $_SESSION['message'] = 'Dispositivo actualizado correctamente';
            }else{
                $_SESSION['message'] = 'No se puso actualizar Dispositivo';
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $_SESSION['message'] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Complete el formulario de edición';
    }

    // header('Location: ../dispositivos/dispositivos.php');
?>
```

***Depuración :***

```
Warning: Undefined array key "foto_dispositivo" in C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\dispositivos\EditarDispositivo.php on line 13

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\dispositivos\EditarDispositivo.php on line 13

Warning: Undefined array key "foto_dispositivo" in C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\dispositivos\EditarDispositivo.php on line 14

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\dispositivos\EditarDispositivo.php on line 14

Warning: Undefined array key "foto_dispositivo" in C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\dispositivos\EditarDispositivo.php on line 15

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\dispositivos\EditarDispositivo.php on line 15

Warning: Undefined array key "foto_dispositivo" in C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\dispositivos\EditarDispositivo.php on line 18

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\dispositivos\EditarDispositivo.php on line 18
string(46) "C:/xampp/htdocs/aplicacion/subida_de_archivos/" SQL: [118] UPDATE dispositivo SET nombre = ?,descripcion = ?,version =?,marca = ?, foto_dispositivo = ? WHERE id_dispositivo = ?; Sent SQL: [131] UPDATE dispositivo SET nombre = 'c',descripcion = 'c',version ='c',marca = 'c', foto_dispositivo = NULL WHERE id_dispositivo = '4'; 

Params: 6 Key: Position #0: paramno=0 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #1: paramno=1 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #2: paramno=2 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #3: paramno=3 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #4: paramno=4 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #5: paramno=5 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2

bool(true)
```

Comment: Agrega el código del formulario.

Comment: Editado Sal  gracias por decirlo !

Comment: En el formulario te falta `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, revisa [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Comment: Es verdad eso mismo me pasó antes en el de insertar y no caí en cuenta ! con las prisas me olvido de esas cosas gracias voy aprobar y te comento !

Comment: Efectivamente era el enctype ya edita y actualiza la foto ! menos mal que era una simple tontería como esa !!!! y yo quebrandome los sesos, gracias un saludo, edito la pregunta y la doy por valida !

Comment: Editado si puedes marcarla como resuelta gracias !

Comment: ok editado, no hay problema mañana mirare como ponerlo en la zona de respuestas , un saludo !

Answer (score 0):

Hola como comentaron los compañeros el problema era que no había puesto el enctype en el formulario y ya actualiza la foto correctamente.

```
<!-- editar -->
<div class="modal fade my-5" id="editar<?php echo $row['id_dispositivo']; ?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="AgregarNuevoDispositivo" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="titulo-modal">Guardar Dispositivo</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <form method="POST" action="EditarDispositivo.php?id_dispositivo=<?php echo $row['id_dispositivo']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-4">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                                    <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-4">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                                    <i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" name="marca" value="<?php echo $row['marca']; ?>" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-4">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                                    <i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" name="version" value="<?php echo $row['version']; ?>" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-4">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                                    <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input type="file" name="foto_dispositivo" value="<?php echo $row['foto_dispositivo']; ?>" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-4">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                                    <i class="fa fa-text-height" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                                <textarea type="text" name="descripcion" class="form-control"><?php echo $row['descripcion']; ?></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```